# How can I draw JavaScript graphical elements on top of custom image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some Javascript drawing random square elements in the DOM. I have a gif (Image) I want these elements to appear over but they keep appearing underneath the gif. I tried defining z-depth and layout parameters to move these elements on top of the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJphM.png), but this produced no difference.

Any assistance in achieving the result (drawing elements onclick, on top of this gif) would be much appreciated.

I ultimately want to draw various other images over this image onclick, restricted to this particular area on top of the gif. If someone can suggest a solution to this as well I would be very much grateful!

(Code features some unused elements from my past attempts)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="div.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div style="cursor: pointer;" id="boxy" >
        <img src="bg.gif" alt="unfinished bingo card" onclick="create()" />

    </div>

</div>

    <script>
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.height = 1300;
        canvas.width = 1300;
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        body.appendChild(canvas);

        var rects = [];

        function create() {
            //  Opacity
            context.globalAlpha = 0.7;
            var color = '#' + Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
            context.fillStyle = color;

            //Each rectangle's size is (20 ~ 100, 20 ~ 100)
            var coordx = Math.random() * canvas.width;
            var coordy = Math.random() * canvas.width;
            var width = Math.random() * 80 + 20;
            var height = Math.random() * 80 + 20;

            var rect = {
                x: coordx,
                y: coordy,
                w: width,
                h: height
            }

            var ok = true;
            rects.forEach(function (item) {
                if (isCollide(rect, item)) {
                    console.log("collide");
                    ok = false;
                } else {
                    console.log("no collision");
                }
            })

            if (ok) {
                context.fillRect(coordx, coordy, width, height);
                rects.push(rect);
            } else {
                console.log('rect dropped');
            }

            console.log(rects);

        }

        function isCollide(a, b) {
            return !(
                ((a.y + a.h) < (b.y)) ||
                (a.y > (b.y + b.h)) ||
                ((a.x + a.w) < b.x) ||
                (a.x > (b.x + b.w))
            );
            
        }
        document.getElementById('boxy').addEventListener('click', create);
        document.getElementById('canvas').style.position = "relative";
        document.getElementById('canvas').style.zIndex = "10";

       
    </script>

</body>

</html>

    #my-div {
    
    width: 1300x;
    height: 1300px;
    z-index: -1;
}
a.fill-div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#boxy {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
     z-index: -1;
}

.canvas {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
     z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `position:absolute;` to take it out of the html flow.

Now anything added after the image will be placed like the image was never there.

```css
img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -10;
}

div {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1664273107076-b6d1fbfb973b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1171&q=80">

<div>Hello i am on top of the image
</div>
```